# Child_changed downloads everything on page load

Tags: javascript, firebase

```
var notifRef = new Firebase(webSocketBaseURL + "/notifications/custom:" + userId);

var $results = $("#notifications_nav"); //div in nav for notifcations

notifRef.limitToLast(5).once("value", function(snapshot) {
    var lastKey = null; // at least 1 key is always present
    var count = 0; // because startAt is inclusive, we have to ignore first child_added
    snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
        addNotifications(data.val());
        lastKey = data.key();
    });
    checkNotifications();
    notifRef.orderByKey().startAt(lastKey).on('child_added', function(snap) {
        if (count > 0) {
            addNotifications(snap.val());
            checkNotifications();
        }
        count++;
    });
});

notifRef.on('child_changed', function(snapshot) {
    var notification = snapshot.val();
    var existingNotif = $results.find('.top-cart-item').eq(0);
    if (notification.type == existingNotif.data("type") && notification.link == existingNotif.find("a").attr('href') && notification.message == existingNotif.find("a").text()) {
        existingNotif.find(".top-cart-item-price.time").livestamp(moment(parseInt(notification.timestamp)).unix());
        existingNotif.find(".top-cart-item-quantity").text("x " + notification.count);
        checkNotifications(); // append +1 to new notifications
    }
});
```

Hello, here is basically problem

When I have the `child_changed` event, on page load all the data from the firebase URL is loaded. Why is `child_changed` loading at all on page load? Should it be just listening if some of the data is changed and then only shooting notification?

I checked the frames under network tab in inspect element and indeed, when `notifRef.on('child_changed')` is commented out, only 5 last notifications are downloaded as it is in `notifRef.limitToLast(5).once("value"`.

Let me know if you want to know more details or what am obvious thing am I missing here?

EDIT:

What is happening in code it is like facebook top right corner notification area for 5 latest notifications.

`notifRef.limitToLast(5).once("value"` this is pulling 5 latest notifications. I'm doing there a loop to get the last key. Now next part is how I realized your most common asked question: how to get children that were added after the page load?

Because in previous part in limitToLast(5) I got the latest key added, with `notifRef.orderByKey().startAt(lastKey).on('child_added'` I am listening to only new added children, since its ordered by key and started from the last one.

Now is the tricky part, since one notification type is `new message from user` and if user sends multiple times, then instead of adding every time new child, the last key just has a new incrementing property `count` which means how many new messages are received from user. But this is only in the case when the last notification was a message from that user. If last notification was not a message from that user and next notification is a new message from user, then it just adds new child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's slice-and-dice your code a bit, to see what's going on:

```
var notifRef = new Firebase(webSocketBaseURL + "/notifications/custom:" + userId);

notifRef.on('child_changed', function(snapshot) {...
```

Note that you're not ordering or limiting the `notifRef` in any way here. So you're listening for `child_changed` events on all children at that location.

But the way you're mixing `value` and `child_` events and the different queries are tricky for me to parse, so I might have misunderstood your use-case.

Comment: updated question. so you're saying to me child_changed downloads all data to browser and tracks in browser, not on server side?

Comment: You're right changing `child_changed` part to `notifRef.limitToLast(1).on('child_changed', function(snapshot) {` did it's job, not all data is loaded. Is there anywhere in documentation mentioned that when using `child_changed` then all data is downloaded into browser? That explains then why we have sooo much bandwidth and so little data stored

Comment: Glad to hear it is solved. It has nothing to do with the specific event type, but with the fact that you attach to an unfiltered location. If you attach a listener to an **unfiltered** location, it will fire events for all data at that location. To prevent that, you filter it by calling limitTo..., startAt, endAt, etc.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, but that still doesn't answer if lets say I have 1000 children and have unfiltered `child_changed` and only the last child is changed, then why all 1000 children are downloaded to browser at the moment of page load and not only the last one when the child was actually changed?

Comment: Firebase is a state synchroniation system, not a message passing aystem. Initially there is no data in the browser, so it synchronizes everything that matches your conditions and fires the appropriate events. If you only want to see events for new data, there are already some questions dealing with that.

Comment: Thanks alot for explanation. Hope others who run into similar problems will find it out too before they are not too deep in production with that kind of issues